# How to disable auto </br> after <td> in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

CKEditor will add `<br>` after `<td>` .. how to disable this or turn off this function?

Before :

```
<td>
<img style="width: 950px; height: 114px;" src="http://www.example.com/uploads/image/Newsletter/Newsletter2.jpg" alt="">
</td>
```

After Save :

```
<td>
<br>
<img style="width: 950px; height: 114px;" src="http://www.example.com/uploads/image/Newsletter/Newsletter2.jpg" alt="">
</td>
```

My setting :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    
    config.toolbar = "MyToolbar";
    config.toolbarCanCollapse = false;
    config.resize_enabled = false;
    config.height = '280';
    config.width = '1100';
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
```

CKEditor Version : 3.6.4

Comment: Are you using some call to `nl2br` in your server code?

Comment: this code is not from me i just doing some maintenace .. and i just found nl2br in code .. after remove, all problem solved.. thanks for mention about nl2br function ..

Comment: I provided that as an answer instead of a comment because for me it was quite obvious the problem, but someone thought that it wasn't worth and deleted it :-(

Answer (score -2):

quick and dirty: after save I would just replace `<td><br>` with `<td>`
This behaviour is not documented, and I don't see a setting to turn it on/off