# How to turn off auto-formating code in CKEditor 3.6.4?

Tags: javascript, html, web, ckeditor

maybe is way to turn off auto-formating HTML code in CKEditor version 3.6.4?

I found only [how to disable auto </br> after <td> in CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720456/how-to-disable-auto-br-after-td-in-ckeditor), but i need to turn off this function.

---

Now i try to save code:

```
{if key is 1}<li>custom text</li>{/if}
```

and i get:

```
<li>

{if key is 1}</li>

<li>

custom text</li>

<li>

{/if}</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditor works with a valid HTML only and text outside `<li>` tags is not valid. Quoting [CKEditor basic concepts](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basics):

> CKEditor is not a tool that will let you input invalid HTML code. CKEditor abides by W3C standards so it will modify code if it is invalid.

You can however try to use [`config.protectedSource`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-protectedSource) to hide these template's markers, but you would need to create a good RegExps to hide only real tags and not any text between `{` and `}`. The simplest implementation that could work would be:

```
config.protectedSource = [
    /{\/?[\w]+(?: [\w\s]+)?}/g
];
```

But the real on will depend on what really may be used in these tags.

Comment: Is way to display protectedSource values in WYSIWYG mode? ;/